# Function not terminating

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, do-while

I have the following code that produces PDF reports from excel data. Reports need to be generaeted on the basis of how many hours are needed - the number of hours can't go past a certain date (the end of the fiscal year). It takes in a certain amount of total hours needed, and produces a certain amount of reports. Reports are capped at 200 hours per report.

So for instance, if there are 524 total hours, then there need to be 3 reports generated - 2 reports of 200 hours, 1 report of 124; unless the total hours is projected to go past the end date. The end date in this example is 6/30/2016.

For example, if I project that a person works 2 hours a day, and the start date of the report is 6/11/2016, then a 200 hour report would translate into 100 days worked, and the end date would then logically be 9/19/2016; except the end date by edict must be 6/30/2016, so it would only be a 19 days report.

The function WritePDFforms takes this information and puts it into a PDF, and does so successfully.  That's not where the problem is.

The problem is that there are 524 total hours needed, and an initial start date of 11/24/2015. The first report should be of 200 hours, or 100 days, meaning that it will end on 3/3/2016. The second report should be of 200 hours, or 100 days, meaning that it will end on 6/11/2016. The third report should be of 38 hours, or 19 days, meaning that it will end on 6/30/2016.

The goal is to save in each iteration of the WritePDFforms function the start date of that specific report. So for instance the first report should have 11/24/2015; the second should have 3/3/2016; the third should have 6/11/2016, and it should stop then because that report will terminate on the end of the fiscal year or 6/30.

The way the code is written is that it runs the boolean check, and updates the extStartDate variable; ultimately returns false, but extStartDate is updated to 6/30/2016, and that's the final value that is saved. I don't want it to run the final time; I want to cut off the program before it goes to the final date, and I know it is the final time because either A) The reports have reached the fiscal cutoff or B) there are no more hours that need to be reported.

In sum - the function checkExtensionNeed runs one too many times. In checkExtensionNeed the last time, the variable extStartDate is updated. I don't want it to iterate the last time, and if it does iterate that last time, I don't want extStartDate to be updated.

```
  Option Explicit



Dim totalHoursNeeded As Long
Dim extStartDate As Date
Dim lastBillableDate As Date
Dim daysRemaining As Long
Dim hoursPerDay As Long
Dim hoursColumn As Long
Dim dateLastApproved As Date
Dim dateLastWritten As Date
Dim startDate As Date
Dim amountLastApproved As Long
Dim amountLastWritten As Long
Dim extensionSheet As Worksheet
Dim totalHoursInExt As Long


'preliminary subroutine, calls writepdfforms
'called from the double click method
'shName = worksheet that gets the double click
'RowNumber = row of the double clicked cell

Public Sub FillSelectedForms(ShName As Worksheet, RowNumber As Long)


Dim cell As Range, wks As Worksheet, Templ As ListObject, ExitLine As Label


Dim i As Long


        Set extensionSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Extensions")

'get template list
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates List")
Set Templ = wks.ListObjects(1)

If Templ.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No data found in Templates List", vbInformation, "Missing Data"
    GoTo ExitLine
End If

'databodyrange = first column in the data (not header) cell 1
Set cell = Templ.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
        For i = 1 To extensionSheet.Range("G1").End(xlToRight).column
            If InStr(1, extensionSheet.Cells(1, i).Text, "Average number of hours") > 0 Then
                hoursPerDay = extensionSheet.Cells(RowNumber, i) / 7
            ElseIf InStr(1, extensionSheet.Cells(1, i).Text, "73 - Total Requested Hours") > 0 Then
                hoursColumn = i
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    'first find total amount of hours needed
        totalHoursNeeded = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(RowNumber, 12)
       'do while
           Do While (checkExtensionNeed(RowNumber)) = True
'                MsgBox ("On iteration " & i & "  Total Hours in Extension is " & totalHoursInExt & " Last Date Written is " & dateLastWritten)
'                i = i + 1
                If totalHoursNeeded >= 200 Then
                    'would a 200 hour extension go past the lastBillableDate?
                    If DateAdd("d", totalHoursInExt / hoursPerDay, extStartDate) > lastBillableDate Then
                        'go up to the last billable date and not further
                        totalHoursInExt = CLng(daysRemaining / hoursPerDay)
                    Else
                        totalHoursInExt = 200
                    End If
                        extensionSheet.Cells(RowNumber, hoursColumn) = totalHoursInExt
                Else
                      'if there is less than 200 hours remaining AND would a full extension go past the last billable date
                      If DateAdd("d", totalHoursInExt / hoursPerDay, extStartDate) > lastBillableDate Then
                            totalHoursInExt = CLng(daysRemaining * hoursPerDay)
                        Else
                            totalHoursInExt = totalHoursNeeded
                      End If
                       extensionSheet.Cells(RowNumber, hoursColumn) = totalHoursInExt


                End If
                WritePDFForms ShName.Name, RowNumber, cell, cell.Offset(0, 1)
                extensionSheet.Cells(RowNumber, hoursColumn + 1) = DateAdd("d", totalHoursInExt / hoursPerDay, extStartDate)
                totalHoursNeeded = totalHoursNeeded - totalHoursInExt
            Loop
            MsgBox (extensionSheet.Cells(RowNumber, hoursColumn + 1))
ExitLine:
Set Templ = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function checkExtensionNeed(Row As Long)

' Find start date of Extension
' Find year/wage pair
' Find total number of hours needed in extension

        Dim summarySheet As Worksheet, extensionSheet As Worksheet, i As Long

        Dim j As Long


        Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
        Set extensionSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Extensions")

        'find dates for comparison
        For i = 1 To extensionSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).column

            'find date of last approved extension

            If InStr(1, summarySheet.Cells(1, i), "Year 1 Most Recent Extension Approval Date") > 0 Then
                dateLastApproved = summarySheet.Cells(Row, i)
            'find date of last written extension
            ElseIf InStr(1, extensionSheet.Cells(1, i), "Start Date (To be Calculcated)") > 0 Then
                dateLastWritten = extensionSheet.Cells(Row, i)
            'find date of start in Project Sweep
            ElseIf InStr(1, summarySheet.Cells(1, i), "Year 1 Start Date") > 0 Then
                startDate = summarySheet.Cells(Row, i)
            ElseIf InStr(1, summarySheet.Cells(1, i), "Year 1 Most Recent Extension Approval Amount") > 0 Then
                amountLastApproved = summarySheet.Cells(Row, i)
            ElseIf InStr(1, extensionSheet.Cells(1, i), "Total Requested Hours") > 0 Then
                amountLastWritten = extensionSheet.Cells(Row, i)
            End If
        Next i

        If dateLastApproved > dateLastWritten Then
            extStartDate = DateAdd("d", amountLastApproved / hoursPerDay, dateLastApproved)
            extensionSheet.Cells(Row, hoursColumn + 1) = extStartDate
        Else
            extStartDate = dateLastWritten
            'extensionSheet.Cells(Row, hoursColumn + 1) = dateLastWritten
        End If

        lastBillableDate = DateAdd("d", 365, startDate)
        daysRemaining = lastBillableDate - extStartDate

        If extStartDate < lastBillableDate And totalHoursNeeded > 0 Then

            checkExtensionNeed = True
        Else
            checkExtensionNeed = False
        End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

your do while never ends since you are not changing rowNumber during the loop

Do While (checkExtensionNeed(RowNumber)) = True
....
loop

you need to make a better statement or make an "exit do" when you have furfilled your request.

And you are also missing some error handling in your function and sub.